# Angular 9: Lazy load modules without arrow function?

Tags: angular, angular9

I have number of modules in a angular app under plugin directory. I keep track of these modules in a json file.

**In angular 8:** 
We lazy load module like this `loadChildren: '.plugins/gallery/gallery.module#GalleryModule'`

**In angular 9:** 
We lazy load module like this `loadChildren : () => import('.plugins/gallery/gallery.module').then(m => m.GalleryModule)`

**Problem**
But Angular 9 approach is not suitable for my use case. Because i am reading modules information from a json file and then construct routes in a loop.

**plugins.json**

```
[
  {
    "path": "gallery",
    "loadChildren": "./plugins/gallery/gallery.module"
  },
  {
    "path": "chats",
    "loadChildren": "./plugins/chats/chats.module"
  }
]
```

**Application main module**

```
    import pluginsList from './plugins/plugins.json';

    const pluginsModules: Route[] = [];

    pluginsList.map(item => {
      pluginsModules.push({
        path: item.path,
        loadChildren: () => item.loadChildren
      });
    });

    export const pluginsModules
```

**Error**

```
Cannot find module ./plugins/gallery/gallery.module
```

Comment: can you please provide demo in stackblitz .com

Comment: any reason why you are keeping those routes details in a json ?

Comment: I bundle modules via cmd. And i only want module to be bundled that are in a json.